# Lager - Parse Transforms

Tags: erlang, lager, parse-transform

I have added Lager to my application using rebar. It compiles fine and Lager starts ok when I start my app.  However, I get undef messages when I call lager:debug/1 which tells me that the `lager_transform` parse transformation is not being picked up, but I have added the following to my rebar.config:

```
{erl_opts, [{parse_transform, lager_transform}]}.
```

and I am of course compiling with rebar.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/basho/lager/issues/60#issuecomment-7583150 ?

Comment: I have now, thanks.  Adding the -compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]). to each module where I need the transforms has resolved my issue.  But, the https://github.com/basho/lager page says this is an alternative to setting the compiler flags, which I have done via rebar.config, assuming this would make the transforms available through the module. Obviously there is something I don't understand going on here.

Comment: You should be able to compile all the files with the `{parse_transform, lager_transform}` option without having the compile flag set in every file. I use erlang.mk and it makes this trivial. I don't know enough about rebar to know why erl_opts isn't working.

Comment: The following absolutely works with rebar
{erl_opts, [{parse_transform, lager_transform}]}.
I use it on Mac OSX, Windows, Ubuntu and have for years. 

Did you do a rebar clean before re-compiling to ensure that all of your beam's had the transform applied?

Comment: @Jr0 seems that was the issue, thanks,\

Answer (score 1):

try add into your module

```
-compile({parse_transform, lager_transform}).
```

and show rebar.config and your code